# Screen Capture/Recording

Tags: video-capture, screen-capture

Recently i've been creating a number of How-To videos e.g. creating WCF services, SQL DB's..

I have always used Windows Media Encoder to record my screen as the output file was near HD quality whilst keep the output file size relatively small.

I have just upgraded my OS from Vista to Win7 64bit and turns out Media Encoder is intended for use with 32bit systems. This may be the reason why the quality of my videos are now very poor.

I've searched the web, and tried programs like:

```
EZVid  
CamStudio  
Screencast-o-matic  
VLC  
Microsoft Expression Encoder
```

Non of which seem to offer 420p/HD quality.

Any other options i can explore? Software must be free/opensource.

Thank you.

Comment: I bet most of those programs have HD quality setting buried somewhere in Options, you just haven't found it. 
Anyway, try FreeScreenToVideo - it might be what you're looking for:
http://www.koyotesoft.com/video-software/free-screen-to-video.html